# Change the contents of redux state using immutable update pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux

I want to update an array content using immutable update pattern.
To be very precise ,I want to make changes to an array of objects "INSIDE" another object "INSIDE" another array of objects.

```
[
  {
        id:'something',
        data:[
            {},{},........text box data need to be added here based on the id match
        ]

  },
  {
        id:'something2',
        data : [
            {},{},{}  ,........text box data need to be added here based on the id match
        ]
  }
]
```

I want to make changes to the data array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3vM.png)

I tried using various patterns of spread operator and i could not update the data array.

All i want is :

1. I have a textbox and a sendbutton.
2. if i add something to the text box and click on send...the id of a particular note is passed where the data is needed to be added.
3. upon matching the id in the global data array , i want to add the provided data in text box to the data array inside each object in the global array.
4. I want to add the new data to the state object so that it can reflect in my screen

Moreover , can i please know a better approach to design my data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.